# CSS firstchild in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm having problems with some CSS that works properly in Chrome and Firefox, but acts unexpectedly in IE 9 and 8.

Here is an example (where `user_info` is a table):

```
.user_info td:first-child+td
{
    padding : 0px;
    background : #b8cce4;
}
```

The problem is that IE doesn't append those attributes.

If I use the webmaster tool(F12) and rename the CSS rule `.user_info td:first-child+td` to, for example, `.user_inf td:first-child+td` and back again, then it perfectly applies the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: You're welcome. If something in CSS doesn't work the way it should, it's best to check the doctype first - it can save a lot of time.

Comment: Having a "wrong" doctype is one of the possible causes of quirks mode, which was the actual cause of the problem in this instance. @user1351206: You should accept Drejon's answer, [here's how to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 3):

If something CSS-related that you'd expect to work in IE9 isn't working, then the first thing you should do is make sure that the page is not being displayed in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

You should be able to check this in the Developer Tools (F12).

Answer (score 0):

try simply

```
.user_info td + td {
    padding : 0px;
    background : #b8cce4;
}
```

which is equivalent to your rule (unless you have nested tables) or using :first-child

```
.user_info tr td:first-child + td {
    padding : 0px;
    background : #b8cce4;
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent unless there are exactly two cells per row. Nested tables are irrelevant here.